# Will vs Would - when writing about he past

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence that I can't figure out.

> I knew that If the pain won’t break me, embarrassment might will.

Or:

> I knew that If the pain wouldn't break me, embarrassment might would.

What's the right way to write it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use '**wouldn't**' (instead of *won't = will not*) if you are a speaking about a *future* possibility in the *past* (relatively to 'knew').
2. You can't combine *2 modal verbs* in the end (might + will), use just 'might'.

> I knew that if the pain wouldn't break me, embarrassment might (do
>   it).